# How to validate phone number and amount

Tags: android, validation

I have been trying to figure the appropriate way to represent phone number and amount. Let me be specific, I have a user form where the user are supposed to fill their phone number and amount. I am from Nepal and we usually have the phone number in format 01-4444445 or 023-454566. I wonder how can I do this? In addition,  in the amount field, i wish to display amount in this format 1,000,000 and so on. For example, when the user enters four digit comma sign should be automatically added to the field. Plz, suggest me the way I can do this. I have been trying this since a week.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search for regex (regular expressions )in Android

Comment: Check out a library called libphonenumber,  depending on the intricacy of your validation.  Forewarning, it's a large library.

Comment: Can sombody elaborate with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this function from TextWatcher (For NTC Prepaid validation)
"^(984|986)\d{7}$" this means phone number starts with 984 or 986 and after that there is 7 digits i.e. total 10 digits

```
phoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(!isValidNumber(s.toString())){
                    isnumbervalid=false;
                    phoneNumber.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
                }else {
                    isnumbervalid=true;
                    phoneNumber.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });


    private boolean isValidNumber(String phonenumber) {
            String PHONE_PATTERN = "^(984|986)\\d{7}$";

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PHONE_PATTERN);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phonenumber);
            return matcher.matches();
        }
```

Comment: how to validate landline number

Comment: have a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542816/how-to-getback-response-from-server/41543297#41543297